# Short variable for DOM methods

Tags: javascript

Can a "shortcut" not be made to methods such as `document.createElement`, `document.createTextNode`, `[element].setSelectionRange` etc?

```
var c = document.createElement;
var div = c('div');
div.innerHTML = 'blah';

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

When executing the above code **Firebug console returns an error**:

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ ::  :: line 20" data: no]

This happens on [jsfiddle as provided here](http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/EEvgA/) and silently fails when done outside of jsfiddle with no errors.

The below code works fine, so is it just limited to DOM manipulation methods?

```
function long_function_name(prop)
{
   alert(prop);
}

var c = long_function_name;

c('blah');
```

---

This has **practical examples for compression** sake:

Instead of:

```
if (element.setSelectionRange)
{
    element.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
}
```

Compress to:

```
var s = element.setSelectionRange || 0;
if (s) s(pos, pos);
```

Comment: Even `var s = element.setSelectionRange;` is sufficient. If the property is not defined, it will return `undefined` which evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Oh thanks @Felix, nice to know! It's a shame this doesn't work because of the context issues, as with the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two obvious issues:

- Calling your aliased functions will not be providing the correct `this` value (it will be the global object rather than `document`), which the DOM method may or may not depend upon;
- DOM nodes in JavaScript are *host objects*, which are not subject to the normal rules of native JavaScript objects and can essentially do what they like. For example, there is no guarantee that a method of a host object is a regular `Function` object and may not therefore have the `call()` or `apply()` methods that you could otherwise use to provide the correct `this` value.

This being the case, you're better off writing a wrapper function instead, such as

```
function c(tagName) {
    return document.createElement(tagName);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, calling `document.createElement` calls the `.createElement` method with `this = document`. When you assign it to a variable, it loses this association.

You have to write a short function to call the method properly. For example:

```
var c = function(name){ return document.createElement(name); };
```

In newer versions of ECMAScript used by some browsers, you have the easier option of

```
var c = document.createElement.bind(document);
```

Unfortunately this is not universally supported.

Comment: FYI in IE 7/8 this kind of stuff works `var w = document.write;`