# Clearing Webview Data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome App with a webview that has a 'persistent partition', I need to have a button that will clear all the data saved in that webview's partition. I've tried the following solution based on the official google samples but I can't get it to work

```
var clearDataType = {
    appcache:true,
    cookies: true,
    fileSystems: true,
    indexedDB: true,
    localStorage: true,
    webSQL: true,
}

function clearCache() {
    document.getElementById('webview-window').clearData(
    { since: 0 }, // Remove all browsing data.
    clearDataType, function() {console.log('cache cleared');});
}
```

The webview in the app is like this:

```
<webview id="webview-window" src="http://www.google.ca" partition="persist:cache1">
```

I'm getting the error: "uncaught typeError:...clearData is not a function" whenever I press the button that runs the clearCache() function above.

I've never worked with webviews this way before so any extra explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check your method call syntax. May be more of a context problem.

From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-clearData) it appears that the call for clearData is directly on to the webview itself.

```
<webview>.clearData( ClearDataOptions options, ClearDataTypeSet types, function callback)
```

Also, this SO post might prove useful for more understanding.
[Short variable for DOM methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290733/short-variable-for-dom-methods/6290767#6290767)

Comment: Isn't the document.getElementById('webview-window') getting the webview itself? I took a look at the thread you linked but I'm drawing the same conclusion. Am I interpreting this wrong?