# Chrome webview's clearData function is identified as nonexistent

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-webview

I want the webview in my Chrome app to clear its cache every time it is started again. I tried using the clearData() function [outlined here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-ClearDataOptions) but the console reports that `...clearData is not a function`. There was an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995953/clearing-webview-data) to someone who had the same problem, but that did not solve it. The getElementById part works, since I was able to change the webview's style with it. The problem is the clearData part.

html bit:

```
<webview class="w" id="webView" src="https://example.com"></webview>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('webView').clearData({start:0},{cache:true});
```

Comment: Try waiting for the webview to initialize e.g. put the code in a `loadstart` event listener.

Comment: Tried this:

`document.getElementById('webView').addEventListener(
  'loadstart',
  function(){
    document.getElementById('webView').clearData(
      {start:0},
        cache:true,
      }
    );
    console.log('cleared');
  }
);`

But it didn't work & never showed up on the console log.